# printing and not executing the result of zsh history expansion on partial search

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, readline, history-expansion

I could do:

`!systemctl:p` to get `systemctl reload bind` result printed (as last command in the history starting with `systemctl` string).

but doing the same with the partial search on the command history:

`!?reload:p` results in `zsh: no such event: reload:p`

the former looks the most recent event in the history that starts with `systemctl` string and prints it on the screen, thanks to `:p` modifier, instead of executing.

i thought `:p` is true for `!?` as well on **any** shell.

and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) also results in `bash: !?reload:p: event not found`.

how can i achieve the printing and not executing of the found command line on partial command history search in common unix shells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Event-Designators) (emphasize mine):

> `!?str[?]`
>
> Refer to the most recent command containing `str`. **The trailing '?' is necessary if this reference is to be followed by a modifier** or
>   followed by any text that is not to be considered part of `str`.

so in your case it's

```
!?reload?:p
```

that is, you need a trailing `?` after the search string.